# ST_3DIntersection with LINESTRING M and POLYGON M

Tags: postgis, postgresql, linear-referencing

I have a database of aircraft positions and I'm trying to develop a way to recreate what airspace looked like at a time T. So my idea was to store each pair of positions as a `LINESTRING M(lon1 lat1 t1, lon2 lat2 t2)` and do a query like:

```
SELECT ST_3dIntersection(s.segment, 'POLYGON M ((-88.346 27.5 1598331600000, -88.346 41.699 1598331600000, -62.155 41.699 1598331600000, -62.155 41.699 1598331600000, -88.346 27.5 1598331600000))'::geometry) itsc
FROM segments s
WHERE ST_3DIntersects(s.segment, 'POLYGON M ((-88.346 27.5 1598331600000, -88.346 41.699 1598331600000, -62.155 41.699 1598331600000, -62.155 41.699 1598331600000, -88.346 27.5 1598331600000))'::geometry)
LIMIT 10
```

to get an approximated `POINT M(lon lat T)` of each aircraft at time T,
but Postgres promptly crashes with:

```
realloc(): invalid old size
2021-08-24 23:13:12.790 GMT [3998987] LOG:  00000: server process (PID 3999192) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
```

If I just query for `ST_3DIntersects` without using `ST_3DIntersection` it doesn't crash. I also tried with Z coordinates instead of M coordinates, same result. Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 3):

*PostGIS* has a small but powerful [set of *Linear Referencing*](http://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#Linear_Referencing) functions to work with trajectories, utilizing the full potential of `M` values:

- interpolating an *isolated event* (a `MULTIPOINT M`, or `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION M` if multiple *events* can be isolated) on the trajectory (`LINESTRING M`) at time `T`:

  ```
  SELECT ST_LocateAlong(s.segment, <T>) AS event
  FROM   segments AS s
  ;

  -- dump GEOMETRYCOLLECTION M / MULTI M contents; may be geometries of different dimensions
  SELECT dmp.geom AS event
  FROM   segments AS s,
         LATERAL ST_Dump(ST_LocateAlong(s.segment, <T>)) AS dmp
  ;
  ```
- interpolating an *event trajectory* (a `MULTILINESTRING M`, or `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION M` if multiple *event trajectories/events* can be isolated) on the trajectory (`LINESTRING M`) between times `T1` and `T2`:

  ```
  SELECT ST_LocateBetween(s.segment, <T1>, <T2>) AS trajectory
  FROM segments AS s
  ;

  -- dump GEOMETRYCOLLECTION M / MULTI M contents; may be geometries of different dimensions
  SELECT dmp.geom AS trajectory
  FROM   segments AS s,
         LATERAL ST_Dump(ST_LocateBetween(s.segment, <T1>, <T2>)) AS dmp
  ;
  ```

Comment: That could definitely be helpful, however after further testing, it seems that `ST_3DIntersects` does not work with M coordinates. Perhaps I should use ZM geometries (using the same value for both Z and M) so that I can take advantage of both `ST_3DIntersects` and `ST_LocateAlong`?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want to achieve with your intersection - but yes, `ST_3DIntersect[s|ion]` won't work without `Z` ordinate. The above approach will get you the position on the `LINESTRING M`s (trajectories) at a any given time `T` - much faster, and a lot simpler.

Comment: I want to retrieve all positions at time T inside a bounding box, so my idea was to calculate the intersection of a LINESTRING that represents a pair of positions at T-x and T+y with a POLYGON that represents a 3d plane of the bounding box at time T. So right now my query is something like:

`SELECT DISTINCT ON (s.id) s.*, ST_GeometryN(ST_LocateAlong(s.segment, T), 1) itpl
FROM segments s
WHERE ST_3DIntersects(s.segment, POLYGON((minX minY T, minX maxY T, maxX maxY T, maxX minY T, minX minY T)))
ORDER BY s.id ASC`